# CMake and Visual Studio version issue in configuration

Tags: visual-studio, opencv, cmake

I have downloaded OpenCV2, Visual Studio 13 and CMake 2.8.11.2 version but while configuring CMake doesn't show option of vc13 in compiler I chose vc12 option for being close but I'm unable to locate OpenCV.sln file. Kindly help me out?

Comment: vc12 is visual studio 2013... that is an internal numbering, you can refer to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B#Internal_version_numbering) to see all available numbers and to which version it corresponds. The sln file is in your "build" folder, you have to folder locations in cmake, it is in the "Where to build the binaries" folder you selected

Comment: @api55 i chosed the already existing build folder as my binary location ,there are other binaries there but not the opencv.sln file?Thanks for help.

Comment: did you click in both bottons, first configure and then generate? did both of them ended succesfully and without any errors?

Comment: Always use the latest version of CMake. It has less bugs and usually supports older compilers, too.